# How to enable color picker c# wpf Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, picker

In Visual Studio 2015, specifically in a wpf application, when creating a style in `windows.resoures` like this:

```
<Window.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="DetailTextStyle" TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="Blue"/>
        </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

The value of the foreground can be edited by double clicking it in properties.(image link has been attached. plz check). But after reinstalling Visual Studio I cannot double click and select color. I am able to do this on my laptop with same installation.

[image: See image showing the value from properties.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to add a brush resource and use it in your value field, try this code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <SolidColorBrush x:Key="TestBrush" Color="Blue"/>

    <Style x:Key="DetailTextStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TextBlock}">
        <Setter Property="Foreground" Value="{StaticResource TestBrush}"/>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
```

instead of double click do right click and pick "Edit Resource"